# How to get windows line ending to work on linux pidgin client

Tags: pidgin

I am using pidgin sipe plugin as alternative for microsoft Lync on my linux system. However, when someone send me a multiline message it gets all merged into 1 long line, so for example this:

```
Hi
How are you?
Did you read my e-mail?
```

Results in:

```
HiHow are you?Did you read my e-mail?
```

Which is actually pretty hard to read. Is there some workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be reported here on github issues : https://github.com/tieto/sipe/issues/8.

Seems to be solved with pidgin 3, but no update for a fix in pidgin 2.10.